# How can I solve for $n$ in this binomial coefficient equation

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How can I solve for $n$ in this binomial coefficient equation?
$${n\choose 3} = {n\choose 9}$$

When I try to expand it using factorials, I get a very, very long equation, involving $n-s$ up to $n^6$

I also know that $n = 12$;

Comment: Binomial coefficients increase, then decrease, with central symmetry. So $n=12$.

Answer (score 2):

You professor or book is trying to get you to think about the relation that 
$$
\binom{n}{m} = \binom{n}{n-m}$$

The meaning is that choosing $m$ objects out of $n$ is the same as selecting the $n-m$ objects *not* to choose.

Thus in your case, $n=12$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\binom{n}{3} = \binom{n}{9}
$$
requires
$$
\frac{9!}{3!} = \frac{(n-3)!}{(n-9)!}
$$
note that $n=12$ is a solution, and whereas LHS is constant, RHS is a strictly increasing function of $n$, so this is the only solution

Comment: 0, 1, and 2 are also (essentially trivial) solutions. :)

Comment: yes, i should have said non-trivial explicitly